# Converting datetime to readable format without library access and that works on all devices

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, mobile-safari

I have a datetime string in the following format: 2016-06-14T11:20:00.

I want to convert it to a more human readable format: 11:20am Tuesday, 06/14/16.

I am doing this in a standalone script without access to any libraries.

This must work on mobile and desktop devices on all major browsers, limiting the usage of toLocaleDateString() and .toLocaleTimeString().

Comment: Have you taken any attempts? Is there a reason you can't use momentjs? Is this homework? I would suggest creating an epoch converter. So start by getting the timestamp, given an hour is 3600 sec, day 86400 sec,  and so on.

Comment: The reason I can't use momentjs is because it's in a third party app that will allow me to write a script but not host any files or libraries.

Comment: Fairly trivial exercise. Parse the initial date and time to get the components, use them to create a Date to get the day number, then format the output. What have you tried? Note that this will be treated as a local date for the system it's parsed on, so may represent a different date and time depending on the host system time zone setting.

Comment: There is an answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751328/date-specific-time-each-day-specific-timezone/37781043#37781043) that includes a function to parse ISO 8601 format date strings. It also has a formatting function that should provide enough of a hint for you to format the date. There are many questions and answers here on both topics.