# Change JS timezone from code itself

Tags: javascript, date

Help me please to solve my problem.
So... I have a Schedule (simple 2 coloumn table of events,with date and time).
1)date and time
2)the event.
And have a list of timezones (simple dropdown list).

- Gmt0
- gmt+1
- ....

The problem is that I want to automatically convert the date oncklick of that lists elements.
First of all I've setted the events times with utc date.

```
var event1Date = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 17, 12, 30, 0, 0));
var hour1=event1Date.getHours();
var minute1=event1Date.getMinutes();
and the same thing with rest of events.
```

method works fine when page loads,It gets the timezone from PC somehow.
but I need the same thing oncklick. How to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Javascript dates are based on a UTC time value. You can create a time value for a specific UTC time as you've done. To get a date for any other time zone, adjust the UTC hours and minutes, then read back the new UTC values. There is an answer to [*Date - specific time each day, specific timezone*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751328/date-specific-time-each-day-specific-timezone/37781043#37781043) that shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks,I'll try that :)